# Zip not uploading :- (

Tags: php, upload, zip

For some reason when trying to upload a zip file this function always returns false. The directories are all set to 0777 for permissions. I'm stumped as to what could be wrong.

```
function uploadProof ( $file, $email )
{
    // Check or create for existing directory
    if ( !is_dir('client_files/'.$email))
    {
        mkdir('client_files/'.$email);
        if ( !is_dir('client_files/'.$email.'/proof/'))
        {
            mkdir('client_files/'.$email.'/proof/');
        }
    }
    // Target path
    $target_path = 'client_files/'.$email.'/proof/';

    // File information
    $filename = date('Y_M_D').$email.'.zip';
    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $file['size'];

    // Blacklist and Max file info
    $max_allowed = (1024 * 1024) * 99; // 99 MB
    $blacklist = array(
        '.pl', '.php', '.phtml', '.php3', '.php4', '.php5'
    );

    // Check filename
    foreach ( $blacklist as $nope)
    {
        if ( preg_match("/$nope\$/i", $filename))
        {
            die("As previously stated, we do not allow php files of any type\n
                to be uploaded to our server.\n\n");
        }
    }

    // Check filesize
    if ( $filesize > $max_allowed)
    {
        die("File is too big, file needs to be less than <em>20MB</em> in size.");
    }
    else
    {
        $target = $target_path.$filename;

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post print_r( $_FILES );

Comment: Array
    (
        [name] => BLAHBLAHfilename.zip
        [type] => application/zip
        [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpzDwFiL
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1358091
    )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to check if the upload actually succeeded, before going on to do what might be a totally useless set of operations:

```
function uploadProof ( $file, $email ) {
   if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       die("Upload failed with error code " . $file['error']);
   }
   ...
}
```

The error codes are defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: FYI: mkdir() can make multiple levels of directories in a single call if you pass in the recursive flag: `mkdir('/some/multi/level/dir', 0777, true);`